# How can I open a .csv file in a folder regardless of name using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, wildcard, fopen

I've got a folder, and I've got a file. The file is `test.csv`, but it could get overwritten and become `pickle.csv` or `sylvester.csv` or `ethiopia.csv`, and so I need a way to open a single file in a folder which will always be a `.csv` file with the name changing all the time. I don't want to have to constantly change the name in the source. I want it automatic.

I essentially want to be able to do something like this:

`$handle=fopen(glob("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SITEPREVIEW/csv_drop_folder/*.csv")[0],"r")`

---

BACK STORY: Someone is `scp`-ing new content to a server and file names change, but function cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have one single csv file. Try using [glob](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function:

```
$csv = glob("$yourDirectory/*.csv")[0];
```

Comment: Ah, yes, `glob`. I've used it before.

Comment: My mistake... confusion with slash vs. backslash.

Comment: Trying to do something like this: `$handle=fopen(glob("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SITEPREVIEW/csv_drop_folder/*.csv")[0],"r")`